# how to sort by 2 columns with one column using a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  well pad  type
 '1A22' 22  a1
 '2A22' 22  a1
 '4A23' 23  a2
```

I'd like to sort dataframe by 2 columns of pad and well, but the 2nd column(well) using the number before 'A', so I am doing like this for key for 2nd column, and I got an error. Thanks for your help

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['pad','well'],key=lambda x1,x2: (int(x1),int(x2.split('A')[0])),ascending=True)
```

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'x2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an intermediate sort key by splitting the strings in column `well` around `A` then changing the dtype type of first split to `int`:

```
df['key'] = df['well'].str.split('A', n=1).str[0].astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['pad', 'key'])
```

Alternative approach 1 (Use `sort_values` twice):

```
df = df.sort_values('pad').sort_values('well', key=lambda s: s.str.split('A', n=1).str[0].astype(int))
```

Alternative approach 2 (Define a custom key func):

```
def keyfunc(s):
    if s.name == 'well':
        return s.str.split('A', n=1).str[0].astype(int)
    return s

df = df.sort_values(['pad', 'well'], key=keyfunc)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   well  pad type  key
0  1A22   22   a1    1
1  2A22   22   a1    2
2  4A23   23   a2    4
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham for quick help. how to do without creating a new column? I'd like to learn to use function in sort_values. Thanks

Comment: Just don't use `df['key']` if you don't want to make a new column.

Comment: also why you have to use str[0]? if I just use split('A')[0], then I got an error of ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3). I don't understand, can you explain it? are you trying to convert list to string? Thanks

Comment: @roudan For indexing the lists inside a pandas series you need to use the `str` accessor, otherwise it will not work. You can read more about the `str `accessor [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

Comment: yes I like the approach 2, which is clean and smart, Thank you, I appreciate it. also thanks for explaining str accessor, I learnt 2 tricks today.